# Most children want to grow up to become like me

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Since yesterday's puzzle still hasn't been solved, I made a very simple one for today.

> Here I stand, in the face of danger,
> Ever battling evil, to you I'm a stranger.
>
> Run away villains, I am here to fight.
> Overcoming all, I am the embodiment of right.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a

> Superhero

Here I stand, in the face of danger,
Ever battling evil, to you I'm a stranger.

> Superheroes save and battle for people.

Run away villains, I am here to fight.
Overcoming all, I am the embodiment of right.

> Superheroes like superman fight villians and try to do right.

Also,

> The first letter of each line spell hero.

And regarding the title

> Children might want to be like batman when they grow up.

Comment: It's part of the answer. I was hoping for just a little more specific though.

Comment: Aargh, 16 seconds!

Comment: Check my explanation for 'stranger'

Comment: This answer is correct in all but the name. If you can finish this sentence, you'll have it. rot13(Ongzna vf n ____ ureb)

Comment: Maybe rot13(fhcre-....) ?

Comment: Now the question is who can post first.

Comment: Ahh thats good @Phylyp

Comment: This is correct, nice edit! I really wanted a simple puzzle for today so the other puzzle I have running can have more focus.

Comment: Great puzzle! @Joe-You-Know

Answer (score 2):

> **A HERO**
>
>  Mostly self evident, first letter of each line

Here I stand, in the face of danger,
Ever battling evil, to you I'm a stranger.

> Heroes identities are masked

Run away villains, I am here to fight.
Overcoming all, I am the embodiment of right.

Comment: It's part of the answer. I was hoping for just a little more specific though.

Comment: More specifically, I'm looking for a rot13: fcrpvsvp xvaq bs ureb, juvpu gur irefrf ersrerapr.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know - thanks for that hint, given that QuantumTwinkie answered before me, and we're both so close, I'll allow him to refine his answer based on your input.